# $C_p(\omega_1)$ is a Lindelöf space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, function-spaces

From time to time I come across the following statement:

> $C_p(\omega_1)$ is a Lindelöf space.

Where can I find a proof of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it.

Problem 316 (and its solution) in Tkachuk's "[A Cp-theory problem book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-7442-6)" (2011), page 280.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1824388)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. The question ask for a reference where one can finds the proof, and the page mentioned contains such proof.

Comment: Uh, then, maybe your question should be changed. You may change your question "Where can I find a proof of this?" to "How do we prove this? Please give me a reference, too."

Comment: @311411 actually this is another book, there are four volumes of Cp-theory problem books by Tkachuk. The one I mentioned is the first one.

Comment: @RDK, perhaps you did not notice the tag [tag:reference-request]

Comment: @311411 Oh, alright. I didn't see the tag of the question when I reviewed this answer.